# Splitting an interface apart and putting it back together again

Tags: typescript

I have a union type C which could either be an A or a B. A and B have an id in common which is a string literal.

I would like to create a function which takes the id separately as the first argument, and the rest of the corresponding interface as the second argument. Then combines them and returns an object of type A or B.

Example:

```
interface A { id: "anA"; payload: string; }

interface B { id: "aB"; payload: number | undefined; }

type C = A | B;

function foo<X extends C>(id: X["id"], allButId: Omit<X, "id">): X {
  return { id, ...allButId }; // Goal: It should understand that the object is a complete X
}

foo("aB", { payload: 123 }); // Goal: type error if payload is a string

foo("anA", { payload: "hello" }); // Goal: type error if payload is a number or undefined
```

Any ideas? Is it even possible?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN7OAEwFzIBEcIqhA3MgA5wCeANgPZz7IDOYUoA5pQL4AoAaEixEKAEKZsrYhIrU6TFgRABXALYAjaMgA+yNSBwQYoCDn5CwtKigDCyALxp9yCeSEwjCMMEYgyDCMjAA8ABrIEAAekMZsyPYAfAAUuAThANqEuIQAugA0yHD09BJqYACSrADyGsBgEUU5OIRJAJQZmALIyFAQYGpQgVi4RQB0kyVlFdXIfJQA9IvIAOLM9ASVYOwAFoxq9DiGxtAcJMdgu3A7VyiMWgBWEL7YCXDICIwaVPQDKOEBIIBMFGCk5IQilgaAxmKwAIwAJgAzPN2ksVusSgQbHYolAoIwoNgYIpYSw3sV2JweF4QuCSGQoWTlLJdhBSoxCGiMWsNjjbChoITicBSTDWZSPuptLoiScTGYQBYBEA)

Comment: Suggestions for a better question title would also be appreciated! :)

Comment: It's not clear to me how much you need the compiler to "understand".  If you give `foo()` a call signature that's easier for it to deal with you can get outputs which are *equivalent* to `A` or `B` but not represented in those terms.  So [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WkGK2W) works.  Does that suffice for your needs?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz Well the goal is to get nice completion in the IDE and type safety. And it looks like that does it! Looks like a nice answer! :)

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say the biggest problem with your original version is that there isn't a good *inference site* for the `X` type parameter.  In

```
declare function foo<X extends C>(id: X["id"], allButId: Omit<X, "id">): X;
```

you are hoping that you can pass in a value of type `X["id"]` and the compiler would infer `X` from that.  But that doesn't happen; the compiler doesn't infer from [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) this way; at one point there was a pull request at [microsoft/TypeScript#20126](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/20126) that would have done this, but it never made it into the language.  So no matter what you pass in as the `id` parameter, the compiler will fail to infer anything useful for `X` and it will fall back to the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) which is `C`.

---

If you want to fix this, the best way to get the compiler to infer a type parameter `X` is to give it a value of type `X` from which to infer it.  So let's change the type parameter to `K extends C["id"]` and have `id` be of type `K`.  Then we have a good chance of inferring either `"anA"` or `"aB"` for `K`:

```
declare function foo<K extends C["id"]>( id: K, ...
```

But now we need to express `allButId` in terms of `K`.  How can we represent the original `X` in terms of `K`?  For that I'd use [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to filter a union `T` to those members assignable to `U`.  In this case `X` would be `Extract<C, {id: K}>`.  And from that we can `Omit` the `"id"` property:

```
declare function foo<K extends C["id"]>( 
  id: K, 
  allButId: Omit<Extract<C, { id: K }>, "id">
) ...
```

And what's the return type?  Well, let's see what the compiler does infer for `{id, ...allButId}`:

```
function foo<K extends C["id"]>( 
  id: K, 
  allButId: Omit<Extract<C, { id: K }>, "id">
) {
  return { id, ...allButId };
}

/* function foo<K extends "anA" | "aB">(
  id: K, allButId: Omit<Extract<C, { id: K; }>, "id">
): { id: K; } & Omit<Extract<C, { id: K;}>> */
```

So it infers the [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `{id: K} & Omit<Extract<C, {id: K}>>`.  Ideally it would be nice if we could annotate the return type as `Extract<C, {id: K}>`; after all, shouldn't those be equivalent?  Well, they probably are, but the compiler doesn't "understand" that:

```
function foo<K extends C["id"]>(
  id: K,
  allButId: Omit<Extract<C, { id: K }>, "id">
): Extract<C, { id: K }> {
  return { id, ...allButId }; //error!
}
```

The idea that splitting a generic type apart and putting it back together should give you the original type is not a concept the compiler understands.  It could verify such an equivalent for a *specific* type, but for a generic like `Extract<C, {id: K}>`, it isn't up to the task. This is currently a design limitation in TypeScript; there's an open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#28884](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884) asking for support for this, but for now, it doesn't exist.

---

So what should we do?  Well, it's possible that you don't actually need the compiler to verify this.  If we just don't annotate `foo()`'s return type and let the compiler infer that intersection, then maybe that's good enough, as long as it can verify the equivalence of, say, `B` and `{id: "aB"} & Omit<B, "id">`:

```
const b: B = foo("aB", { payload: 123 }); // okay

foo("aB", { payload: "oops" }) ; // error!
// -------> ~~~~~~~  string is not number

const a: A = foo("anA", { payload: "hello" }); // okay
```

The compiler is happy for you to annotate `b` as `B` and `a` as `A`.  And the compiler complains if you try to call `foo()` with mismatched parameters.  So this all looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Excellent answer @jcalz ! Thank you! Super interesting with the links and the insight you have into what's going on with TypeScript as a language/compiler!